# Verficar se é palíndrome (No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `==')

Tags: haskell

Obtive o segundo erro no código:

No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='

Código:

```
--Verifica se a lista é um palíndromo
palin :: MList a -> Bool
palin(x)
    |x==reverter(x) = True

--Reversão de lista na cauda
reverter:: (MList a) -> (MList a)
reverter(x) = reverteraux(x, Nil)
    where
         reverteraux:: (MList a, MList a) -> MList a
         reverteraux((Cons h t), a) = reverteraux( t, (Cons h a))
         reverteraux(Nil, a) = a
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na tua função estas a comparar duas instâncias de um tipo (genérico) utilizando ==. Isto impõe uma restrição, implica que o tipo não pode ser completamente arbitrário. O tipo tem que ser uma instância de `Eq`, visto que a assinatura de == é `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`.

Podes corrigir o problema adicionando uma restrição na tua assinatura da função `palin`

```
palin :: Eq a => MList a -> Bool
```